# lsl Linden Scripting Language error llSetPrimitiveParams error running rule #1 (PRIM_POINT_LIGHT): time exceeded

Tags: linden-scripting-language

since last rolling restart I am getting this error in the error console of the region I am renting (Homestead):

> llSetPrimitiveParams error running rule #1 (PRIM_POINT_LIGHT): time
>   exceeded.

The same error is coming from different object, of differnet kinds - all using light/glow scripted features, for example:

> ```
>     llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast(LINK_THIS,[PRIM_FULLBRIGHT,ALL_SIDES,TRUE]);
>     llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast(LINK_THIS,[PRIM_POINT_LIGHT, 0, <255.0,126.0,126.0>, 1.0, 20.0, 2.0]);
>     llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast(LINK_THIS,[25,ALL_SIDES,0.0]);
>     llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast(LINK_THIS,[PRIM_MATERIAL,0]);
> ```

In a timer event.

All the objects have been working just fine since the last 2-3 years. I am getting the error since a week but no idea what might be causing it as nothing changed on the sim since the last rolling restart.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://jira.secondlife.com/browse/BUG-224991?) after the latest update. There's nothing you can do to fix it, and thanks to LL's locked JIRA, you can't comment on the bug. So you'll have to wait.